# REPLACE string in MySQL but only specified part

Tags: mysql, replace

i would like to replace string in my query but only on the end of the string this is my example:

```
SET @exampleString = 'example_a_chapter_a';

SELECT REPLACE(@exampleString ,'_a','_b1');
```

Result what I get is this: **example_b1_chapter_b1**
But i would like this: **example_a_chapter_b1**

But there can be more time the **'_a'** in the string as this **'example_a_type_a_chapter_a'**, but
i would like to replace just the end **'_a'** of the string.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be tricky since MySQL can not replace by regex. One of possible ways is:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT(@exampleString, '#END'), '_a#END', '_b1'), '#END', '');
```

-i.e. add something that 100% is not in original string, to it's end and then replace.

Edit: second `REPLACE` is needed in case if original string doesn't end with `_a` (so you'll need to remove added `#END`)

Comment: In my case there is everytime '_a' on the end

Answer (score 2):

You could not use `replace()` at all.  Just reconstruct the string:

```
select (case when @exampleString like '%_a'
             then concat(left(@exampleString, length(@exampleString) - length('_a')),
                         '_b1'
                        )
             else @exampleString
         end)
```

This has the advantage that it works even when the string doesn't end in `'_a'`.